# Multijob in Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

This is my first post here. I am a newbie in YAML and a beginners in Jenkins. I have a requirement where I have to create a `multijob project` using Jenkins Job builders where `project names` I want to store as a variable.
so  the intention is explained below:

Job definition of Multijob Project:

```
job:
  name: test_job
  project-type: multijob
  builders:
    - multijob:
        name: PhaseOne
        condition: SUCCESSFUL
        projects:
          - name: PhaseOneJobA
            current-parameters: true
            git-revision: true
          - name: PhaseOneJobB
            current-parameters: true
            property-file: build.props
```

I want to store following part in a List variable let's say : **JobsList**

```
          - name: PhaseOneJobA
            current-parameters: true
          - name: PhaseOneJobB
            current-parameters: true
```

as

```
 jobsList:
          - name: {list}
            current-parameters: true
```

where *list* is

```
list:
  -JobA
  -JobB
```

so that I can use JobsList in my multijob definition. Something like this:

```
job:
  name: test_job
  project-type: multijob
  builders:
    - multijob:
        name: PhaseOne
        condition: SUCCESSFUL
        projects: JobsList
```

and it expands into

```
  job:
  name: test_job
  project-type: multijob
  builders:
    - multijob:
        name: PhaseOne
        condition: SUCCESSFUL
        projects:
          - name: JobA
            current-parameters: true
          - name: JobB
            current-parameters: true
```

Any suggestion , how to do this?

-Archna

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure you cannot do that. I am pretty noob to above too, but I only saw so far your extended version.

My advice is that if you would be able to implement a what you want, using variables, it would be too confusing and hard to follow. Just keep it basic and have a normal list:

```
projects:
  - name: JobA
    current-parameters: true
  - name: JobB
    current-parameters: true
```